# Websolr, Heroku - NGramFilterFactory seemingly not working on production, works on Dev

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, solr

I have a number of models searchable by sunspot - both are set up for partial words and both work fine in dev, but neither is making successful searches on partial words when I go to production (Heroku + Websolr), though everything else seems fine.

schema.xml -

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I've run

```
heroku run rake sunspot:solr:reindex
```

and

```
heroku run rake sunspot:reindex(5000)
```

The search is fine on the various fields I'm searching, and fine with uppercase and lowercase text entry, but whilst it passes on partial words on my local machine, it fails on Heroku.

Has anyone else come across this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy your dev 'schema.xml' into the production 'schema.xml' through addons:open websolr, and reindex.

This answer is useful also - [Heroku - RSolr::Error::Http (RSolr::Error::Http - 404 Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26548459/heroku-rsolrerrorhttp-rsolrerrorhttp-404-not-found)